# Mac OSX cocoa app takes huge amount of ram with garbage collection

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, memory-management, garbage-collection

im writing a video recorder application for mac with cocoa, and have a huge problem with memory usage.

When launching the app, i have a window with two buttons that i can change view with and a simple custom view where the webcam get loaded. Just this view takes 21mb of ram, when i press on one of the buttons i change the custom view to a QTMovie of the content recorded from the cam.

Every time i change view my app fills upp with about 10mb of ram, and never stops. I have garbage collection on. Even if I show the view of the QTMovie and wants to press the button to display it again, its takes more ram.

Code that loads the subview, trigged from the button

```
 if ([myCurrentViewController view] != nil)
    [[myCurrentViewController view] removeFromSuperview];



        NSViewController* cameraViewController2 = [[NSViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"kVideo" bundle:nil];
        if (cameraViewController2 != nil)
        {
            myCurrentViewController = cameraViewController2;    
        }


[myTargetView addSubview: [myCurrentViewController view]];
```

And this is what happens when the the videoView loads, and this takes 10mb of ram every time i want it to display.

```
-(void)playMovie
{

[movieView setMovie:nil];

NSString* moviePath = [NSBundle pathForResource:@"tempFile" ofType:@"mov" inDirectory:@"/Users/Shared/"];
QTMovie* movie = [[QTMovie alloc] initWithFile:moviePath error:nil];


[movieView setMovie:movie]; 

}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{    

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receiveEvent3:) name:@"updateVideoPlayer" object:nil];

[self playMovie];
}
```

Comment: can you verify that this has something (or nothing) to do with garbage collection, by running without GC (also assuming there are no leaks). depending on the size of the video, the allocation sizes could be reasonable. Instruments (or similar tools) will point out who's creating these allocs, any in what calls. 30 MB total to stream and display a video from disk is not necessarily terrible -- it depends on the conditions.

Comment: If i turn off garbage collection and don't do any manual memory management the app crashes when i change views, if i do some manual dealloc i seem to get the same problems as with garbage collection i just found out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i solved it, every time i pressed a button to change a view, i allocated the new view with something like this `SViewController* cameraViewController2 = [[NSViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"kVideo" bundle:nil];`, and they never got released or thrown away or whatever they should do. Now instead i allocate my views in one place, and just refer to the allocated views when i press new buttons.

Answer (score 1):

I would run your app through Instruments with the Object Graph and Garbage Collection Instruments on. From what your describing it sounds like you have a root object reference to something like an array and you are allocating objects and adding them to this reference but never removing them. The only way the garbage collector knows how to collect something is if all root objects (and any objects referenced through root objects) no longer have a reference to an object.

I'd bet that you still have references to these objects somehow, and you just need to use the object graph to see how you still have a reference to it.

Comment: It seems like every time i change a view the old objects views are still allocated somehow. I thought this snippet would do the trick  if `([myCurrentViewController view] != nil)
    [[myCurrentViewController view] removeFromSuperview];`, they get removed from the view but are still in memory. What do you mean with all root objects, can you link some documentation on that topic?

Comment: Here is the documentation: http://goo.gl/JwFzC Essentially what I might do is use the heapshot in instruments and make sure you know exactly what objects are being allocated everytime you do this and then use the object graph to see how these objects are still being referenced from the root objects. Once you remove these references the garbage collector will collect them.

Comment: My Mac crashes when running instruments as it only has 1.25gig ram and is slow so can try it :( could this be something? `camRecorder(319,0xb032b000) malloc: *** auto malloc[319]: error: GC operation on unregistered thread. Thread registered implicitly. Break on auto_zone_thread_registration_error() to debug`

Comment: wow never seen that before. I would definitely do like it says and break on auto_zone_thread_registration_error() and see what the stack trace says. Definitely need to get some initial data to see what is going on and then narrow down the problem

Comment: Seems to be some problem with the C phidghet api i use in my program, armless message tho